# Game of life problems, C++

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

I am having problems with my Game Of Life assignment. There are two things not working correctly:

1. The game runs too many generations (twice the number entered)
2. It does not update the generations properly: Predetermined state 2 is a static state. This, however, dies as well.

I have checked and re-checked my alive-or-dead conditions and compared them to numerous examples found on the Internet, but I can not find anything. Any comments or pointers are greatly appreciated! :)

### Here's the code:

functions.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

void dspIntroMenu()
{
    cout << "Welcome to the Game Of Life! Please make a choice below" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Press \"P\" to play!" << endl;
    cout << "Press \"R\" to read more about the Game Of Life." << endl;
    cout << "Press \"Q\" to quit." << endl;
    cout << endl << "Choice: ";
}


void whatIs()
{
    cout << "The game of life ........";
}

void playMenu()
{
    cout << "Press \"P\" to choose from predetermined initial states." << endl;
    cout << "Press \"R\" to randomize." << endl;
    cout << endl << "Choice: ";
}

void dispPredStates()
{
    cout << "Please choose between the following states" << endl << endl;
    cout << "    State 1" << endl << "--------------" << endl;
    cout << "   1 0 1 1" << endl << "   0 0 0 0" << endl << "   1 0 1 0" << endl << "   0 1 1 1" << endl << endl;

    cout << "    State 2" << endl << "--------------" << endl;
    cout << "   1 1 1 0" << endl << "   0 1 1 1" << endl << endl;

    cout << "    State 3" << endl << "--------------" << endl;
    cout << "   0 1 0 1" << endl << "   1 1 0 0" << endl << "   0 1 0 1" << endl << "   1 1 1 0" << endl << endl;
}
```

function.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

void dspIntroMenu();
void whatIs();
void playMenu();
void dispPredStates();
int neighbours(int i, int j, int (*game)[21], int x, int y);


#endif
```

in4.cpp, the "main"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
//#include <windows.h>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    static int size = 22;
    int neighAlive, go=0, gen;
    int game[size][size];
    int gameTemp[size][size];
    char mChoice;


    //Fyll matriserna med nollor:
    for (int i=0; i<=size-1; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<=size-1; j++)
        {
            game[i][j] = 0;
            gameTemp[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    //%-----------------------------%

    dspIntroMenu();
    cin >> mChoice;

    while (go==0)
    {
        char pMenuChoice;
        int psChoice, help;

        switch (mChoice)
        {
            case 'p':
            case 'P':
                cout << "How many generations do you wish to view?: ";
                cin >> gen;
                cout << endl << endl;
                playMenu();
                cin >> pMenuChoice;

                switch (pMenuChoice)
                {
                    case 'p':
                    case 'P':
                        dispPredStates();
                        cout << "Choice: ";
                        cin >> psChoice;
                        if (psChoice == 1)
                        {
                            game[9][9] = 1; game[9][10] = 0; game[9][11] = 1; game[9][12] = 1;
                            game[10][9] = 0; game[10][10] = 0; game[10][11] = 0; game[10][12] = 0;
                            game[11][9] = 1; game[11][10] = 0; game[11][11] = 1; game[11][12] = 0;
                            game[12][9] = 0; game[12][10] = 1; game[12][11] = 1; game[12][12] = 1;
                        }
                        else if (psChoice == 2)
                        {
                            game[10][9] = 1; game[10][10] = 1; game[10][11] = 1; game[10][12] = 0;
                            game[11][9] = 0; game[11][10] = 1; game[11][11] = 1; game[11][12] = 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            game[9][9] = 0; game[9][10] = 1; game[9][11] = 0; game[9][12] = 1;
                            game[10][9] = 1; game[10][10] = 1; game[10][11] = 0; game[10][12] = 0;
                            game[11][9] = 0; game[11][10] = 1; game[11][11] = 0; game[11][12] = 1;
                            game[12][9] = 1; game[12][10] = 1; game[12][11] = 0; game[12][12] = 0;;
                        }
                        break;
                        go=1;
                    case 'r':
                    case 'R':
                        srand(time(0));
                        for(int i=9; i<=12; i++)
                        {
                            cout << endl;
                            for (int j=9; j<=12; j++)
                            {
                                help = rand() % 3;
                                if (help == 2)
                                {
                                    game[i][j] = 0;
                                }
                                else {game[i][j] = 1;}

                                //cout << game[i][j] << " " << endl;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }
                go=1;
                break;

            case 'r':
            case 'R':
                whatIs();
                break;

            case 'q':
            case 'Q':
                return 0;

            default:
                cout << "Please press \"P\", \"R\" or \"Q\": ";
                break;
        }
        break;
    }

    //The real game starts here!
    for (int k=0; k<=size-1; k++)
        {
            for (int l=0; l<=size-1; l++)
            {
                cout << game[k][l] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
        cout << "Press enter to continue...";
        cin.get();
        //system("pause");
        //system("cls");

    for (int tid=1; tid<=gen; tid++)
    {
        for (int i=1; i<=size-2; i++)
        {
            for (int j=1; j<=size-2; j++)
            {
                neighAlive = game[i-1][j] + game[i+1][j] + game[i][j-1] + game[i][j+1] + game[i-1][j-1] + game[i+1][j-1] + game[i-1][j+1] + game[i+1][j+1];
                if ((game[i][j] == 1 && neighAlive < 2) || (game[i][j] == 1 && neighAlive > 3))
                {
                    gameTemp[i][j] = 0;
                }
                else if (game[i][j] == 0 && neighAlive == 3)
                {
                    gameTemp[i][j] = 1;
                }

            }
            //cout << endl;
        }
        for (int k=0; k<=size-1; k++)
        {
            for (int l=0; l<=size-1; l++)
            {
                game[k][l] = gameTemp[k][l];
                cout << game[k][l] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        //Sleep(1000);
        //system("pause");
        //system("CLS");
        cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
        cout << "Press enter to continue...";
        cin.get();
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i<=size-1` is the same as `i<size`

Comment: I am aware of that, i used the first one to make it easier to read :)

Comment: I disagree on which is easier to read...

Comment: Just to nitpick, you should really keep to one language when writing comments, and if posting to an international site that language should probably be English. The chance of having another Swede looking at and answering your questions is quite slim... :)

Comment: **Is 'i' less than or equal to the size minus 1** versus **Is 'i' less than size**. It's a bad habit, so try to avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

```
                    break;
                     go=1;
```

> **Your go is never reachable** and it will loop forever. Place it before break.

Comment: There's another `go=1` in the upper level switch.

Comment: @Andrey:- Look again... but for switch 'p' this time :)

Comment: You might misunderstand me. `go=1` is not reachable in the place you found it, but there's another one a level up which is reachable, and the net effect that it is working :)

Answer (score 3):

I see a logic flaw here

```
        if ((game[i][j] == 1 && neighAlive < 2) || (game[i][j] == 1 && neighAlive > 3))
        {
            gameTemp[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else if (game[i][j] == 0 && neighAlive == 3)
        {
            gameTemp[i][j] = 1;
        }
```

What would `gameTemp[i][j]` be initialized to when none of conditions in `if` statements hold?

Comment: I added a else {gameTemp[i][j] = game[i][j];} and it's "better" now. Still some update issues though...

Comment: a cin.ignore was messing up the input. This and the missing else statement was the problem. Thank you all very much :)